# How to control the behaviour of QGridLayout

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

Using PyQT6

I am trying to create and app that adds a new frame (stack1) whenever the check box is clicked. It all works well until the app hides the stack when you untick the checkbox.

[image: original app]
[image: after adding the stack][image: after hiding the stack]

Clearly what I'd like is for the app to return to the initial shape when I hide the stack. I am aware that since I have added a column to the QTGrid,the window has likely reshaped taking into account the extra space. I am getting the same behaviour using deleteLater. So  my question is how can I avoid that? Is there a way to reset the gridLayout to go back to just 1 column?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QStackedWidget, 
QLabel, QPushButton
import sys
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6 import QtGui

class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Anticoagulant Dose calculator") 
        self.buttons = {'metrics': ['Age?', 'Height in cm?', 'Serum Creatinine?', 'Weight in kg?', 'Sex?'],
     'anticoagulant': ['DOAC', 'warfarin, \nacenocumarol'],
      'indication': ['VTE',  'Atrial Fibrilation', 'Mechanical Heart valve'],
       'VTE': ['single VTE > 12 months', 'VTE 3-12 months or  \n multiple, large volume PE or \n active cancer', 'VTE < 3 months \n or known antithrombin deficiency or \n antiphospholipid syndrome'],
        'af': ['No',"Yes, within the past 12 months","Yes, within the past 3 months"],
         'Mech': 'mech',
         'sexo': ['Male', 'Female']}

        self.dialogLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.anticoagLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.rejillaLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.anticoagButtongroup = QButtonGroup()
        self.indicationButtongroup = QButtonGroup()

        self.UIcomponents()
        self.setLayout(self.rejillaLayout)

        self.stack1 = QWidget()
        self.stack1UI() 

    def stack1UI(self):
        for a in self.buttons['anticoagulant']:
            self.anticoag_rb = QRadioButton(a)
            self.anticoagButtongroup.addButton(self.anticoag_rb)
            self.dialogLayout.addWidget(self.anticoag_rb)
    
        for i in self.buttons['indication']:
            self.indication_rb = QRadioButton(i)
            self.indicationButtongroup.addButton(self.indication_rb)
            self.dialogLayout.addWidget(self.indication_rb)
        self.stack1.setLayout(self.dialogLayout)



    def cb_onclicked(self):
        self.cbox = self.bridgingCheckBox.sender()
        try:
            if self.cbox.isChecked():
                print('Puenteando')
                self.rejillaLayout.addWidget(self.stack1, 0, 2)
                self.stack1.show()               
            else:
                self.stack1.deleteLater()
                print('No puenteando')
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

    def UIcomponents(self):
        self.entries = {}
        formas = QFormLayout()
        for m in self.buttons['metrics']:
            if m != 'Sex?':
                self.ent = QLineEdit()
                formas.addRow(m, self.ent)
            
            else:
                print('Sexo?')
                self.sComboBox = QComboBox()
                self.sComboBox.addItems(self.buttons['sexo'])
                sLabel = QLabel('Sex:?')
                sLabel.setBuddy(self.sComboBox)
                formas.addRow(sLabel, self.sComboBox)
            

        self.entries[m] = self.ent
        self.bridgingCheckBox = QCheckBox("Bridging dose")
        self.bridgingCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.cb_onclicked)
        formas.addRow(self.bridgingCheckBox, None)
        self.rejillaLayout.addLayout(formas, 0, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 160)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That does not seem to work, I still get the same behaviour, the window remains like in the after hiding the widget and applying the resize.

Comment: You should Just hide/show the stack instead of deleting it. Add the stack to the layout in `__init__`, and `hide()` it. Then change to button-handler to `self.stack1.setVisible(self.bridgingCheckBox.isChecked()); self.adjustSize()`.

Comment: Great, that worked a treat! Thank you, will publish as an answer and will credit you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks yo @ekhumoro for the answer:

gridding the stack at the init stage then hiding it, and then adding the code to the checkbox connector does it.

```
def cb_onclicked(self):
    self.cbox = self.bridgingCheckBox.sender()
    self.stack1.setVisible(self.bridgingCheckBox.isChecked())
    self.adjustSize()
```